# Individual declarations in merged declaration 'DepartmentListComponent' must be all exported or all local.ts(2395) Routing components

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have a problem with this code, I do it exactly like the video tutorial (I'm learning), but it doesn't work and calls for some declarations. It is possible that the code written in the guide is in some older methodology? Its hard code without service.

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DepartmentListComponent } from './department-list/department-list.component';
import { EmployeeListComponent } from './employee-list/employee-list.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'departments', component: DepartmentListComponent },
  { path: 'employees', component: EmployeeListComponent }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponents  [DepartmentListComponent, EmployeeListComponent ]
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule, routingComponents } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    routingComponents
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<h1> Welocme in routing</h1>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I need to see running application with changing urls form http://localhost:4200/employees and http://localhost:4200/departments.
I am begginer so please be understanding.

Comment: What error you are getting

Comment: Cannot GET /  - in browser
Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'DepartmentListComponent'.
Individual declarations in merged declaration 'DepartmentListComponent' must be all exported or all local.
Individual declarations in merged declaration 'EmployeeListComponent' must be all exported or all local.
Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'EmployeeListComponent'.
Block-scoped variable 'DepartmentListComponent' used before its declaration.
Block-scoped variable 'EmployeeListComponent' used before its declaration.
',' expected. - that is strange ;p

Comment: Individual declarations in merged declaration 'DepartmentListComponent' must be all exported or all local.
Individual declarations in merged declaration 'EmployeeListComponent' must be all exported or all local.

Comment: Looks like the last line in your `app-routing.module.ts` is causing the error.
Try to remove the `routingComponents` export from the `app-routing.module.ts` file and import them explicitly in the `app.module.ts`

Comment: There is no way to make from them array to import all of components in one package?

Comment: you can use .concat on your declarations array. 

declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ].concat(routingComponents),

Comment: in app.module.ts? but he have 9 errors in app-routing.module.ts @up

Comment: I believe issue here is with your const routingComponents in app-routing.module.ts because you are defining a const variable but not assigning value to it so try assigning value with = and it should resolve your issue

Comment: Maybe you can try checking if there is any constructor(){} missing in the class

Answer (score 52):

You are exporting `DepartmentListComponent` in this file which is imported in the same file module locally.

Comment: I was exporting a class with the same name as an Interface

Answer (score 30):

When we `import` and `export` same module in same file, this error is thrown.

Checkout the all imports and make sure that those are not exported from same file.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here with even stranger resolution:
Remove the export line (last line).
Compile (normally without errors)
Add the last line again.
Compile...
Done.
Don't ask me why. I am also a starter learning typescript and Angular along the way ;-)

Comment: Please make the part which can be considered a solution to the described problem more obvious. I believe there is one, but in the current phrasing this risks to be mistaken for a "Me too."

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't think "turning it off and on again" is much of an answer anyway. VTD.

Comment: It is not a question of "good answer or not". It is about not being flagged for not even trying to answer. @miken32 And I accept this as an honest attempt to answer.

Comment: @miken32 I Make the same steps here, searching for the same error on Webstorm IDE and works, definitely is a right answer.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem using Webstorm, a restart + cache clean solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error on a newly created and exported interface. Adding the 'Interface' suffix to the interface name solved it for me.

Change:

```
export interface SomeThing {}
```

To:

```
export interface SomeThingInterface {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this error message when accidentally exporting the same interface twice from the same file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't re-export an `import` as a `const`. So

```
export const routingComponents  [DepartmentListComponent, EmployeeListComponent ]
```

should be

```
export const routingComponents = [DepartmentListComponent, EmployeeListComponent]
```

or

```
export { DepartmentListComponent, EmployeeListComponent }
```

Answer (score 0):

On intellij IDEs, I found that removing the export and adding it again (before the instance, not the class) worked.

I had

```
// x.ts
export class X {}
```

```
// y.ts
import {X} from "./x.ts"
export const instance = new X();  // the export to be removed in my case
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I was trying export the module with same name as that of the const variable.

Ex:

```
export const DepartmentListComponent = [DepartmentListComponent]
```

When I gave different name, it started working fine, hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I was importing an interface in a file that had an exported react functional component with same name.

```
import {Button} from "../../models";



export const Button: React.FC<Button> = () => {
  return (
    <>
      
    </>
  );
};
```

So I changed the name of the interface to `ButtonConfig` and it was fixed